# Fresh install of Fedora 14 is blocking Apache, FTP, etc

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall, fedora

This is puzzling to me because I did a fresh-install, coming from Fedora 14 where I did not have this issue at all. The firewall appears to be blocking all of my services, if I stop the iptables service then I can connect.

Out of 'iptables -L -n -v'

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) 
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
5842 5881K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    
33  1932 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
1113 64847 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) 
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4897 packets, 450K bytes) 
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think packages in Fedora install firewall rules to allow themselves.  Generally in the firewall setup part of the install you have to add access for http and other ports.

Look at the /etc/sysconfig/iptables script file.  In there you will see a rule for tcp port 22 (ssh).  You can copy that rule and change the port to 80.  Then run "iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables" Or just use the firewall configuration tool to add access for the additional ports you need.

Comment: Thanks. This did the job. Do you have any tips for managing a firewall?

Comment: There are tools but I would recommend just figuring out iptables.  It isn't too hard for most basic cases.  Fedora default policy of DENY is a good one, just open up only the ports you need.  And for those you might want to restrict it further by allowing new connections from selected source IP addresses only using the -s <SRC IP> switch.